# Synchronization between GUI Updating thread & processing thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, serial-port, queue

I have developed one application in which i am continuously sending request and reading response at serial port and updating huge GUI comprise of zed graphs, objectlistviews, analog meters.

Currently i am using one thread which is performing request & response at serial port and pushing the data into queue , and another thread which is fetching data from queue and  updating the GUI. 
for this i am making the use of Autoresetevent(Set and waitone) for notifying the GUI thread when data is available in the Queue.

This is actually sequential operation so whatever data comes at serial port should be immediately updated into GUI.  Something like below model

1 Response -> Update GUI -> 2 Response -> update GUI -> 3 Response -> update GUI -> so on ..

Whenever i get any error at the serial port complete model get mess up and GUI is not updated properly.

Can anybody please let me know what approach should be implemented for achieving the above?

As English is not my first language, let me know if anybody needs further improvements in the question.

.net framework 3.5 SP1 and VS 2008

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: What's the target .NET framework version and what's your Visual Studio version?

Answer (score 0):

sent methods can be called from gui thread, it is OK. Problem is on receiving. You can simply set checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls to false and directly call main (gui) thread method within serial port's datareceived method. However I would not use this method.

I would prefer calling a delegate method to update GUI.